Cannot handle supplied parameter spec: must be passed IES parameters java
I'm trying to use java for encrypt/decrypt text using "secp256r1"
But unfortunately I can't it always produce error  "Cannot handle supplied parameter spec: must be passed IES parameters"
Here is the full code example
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.ECKeyPairGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.spec.ECGenParameterSpec;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Generator {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        // Create KeyPairGenerator for ECC
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
        ECGenParameterSpec ecSpec = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(ecSpec);

        // Generate Key Pair
        KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
        PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();

        // Output the keys
        System.out.println("Private Key: " + privateKey);
        System.out.println("Public Key: " + publicKey);
        // Message to encrypt
        String originalMessage = "This is a secret message!";

        // Convert to bytes
        byte[] messageBytes = originalMessage.getBytes();

        // Encrypt the message
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("ECIES", "BC");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        byte[] encryptedMessage = cipher.doFinal(messageBytes);

        System.out.println("Encrypted Message: " +     Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedMessage));

        byte[] encryptedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedMessage);

        // Decrypt the message
        Cipher cipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("ECIES", "BC");
        cipher2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        byte[] decryptedMessage = cipher2.doFinal(encryptedBytes);

        System.out.println("Decrypted Message: " + new String(decryptedMessage));
    }

}


I tried to remove BC but no result
the full exception :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot handle supplied parameter spec: must be passed IES parameters
at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.IESCipher.engineInit(Unknown Source)
at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1296)
at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1236)
at com.example.Main.main(Main.java:42)


I cannot reproduce your error message. Please post your Java and BC version. But there is a (different) issue:

encryptedMessage is not Base64 encoded, which is why it must not be Base64 decoded, i.e. use encryptedMessage directly when decrypting (or alternatively byte[] encryptedBytes = encryptedMessage). With this, the code works on my machine, see https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/1jyD.

Thankx. but the exception is before the encrypted message the exception is produced in the line
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
I use java 17 , bouncycastle  1.75 , jdk15to18

[edit] your question to include a copy of the full stack trace, formatted in a [code block].

I'm using bouncycastle 1.77 and I do not get that exception.

The error message can be avoided if you pass an IESParameterSpec instance as third parameter to cipher.init() during encryption and decryption. As mentioned by President James K. Polk, this is not necessary as of v1.77, so it is easiest to use a more recent BC version.

Thanjx. Confirmed. I tried the version 1.77 and it works perfect

It's the version of bouncycastle.
when use bcprov-jdk15on 1.70 it works perfect
But when use bcprov-jdk15to18 1.75 it produces the exception.
I used the version 1.77 the problem has gone. It's the latest version now on the time I wrote this answer

There is no need to use bcprov-jdk15on, v1.70. It also works with bcprov-jdk15to18, v1.75, if a IESParameterSpec instance is passed as the third parameter in cipher.init(). As of v1.77, the IESParameterSpec instance no longer needs to be passed.

Thankx I just edited the answer
